# keep query string or use mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have seen big company such as facebook, google or yahoo etc use a mix of mod write and query string,

facebook:

```
https://www.facebook.com/zxzxzx
https://www.facebook.com/events/upcoming?action_history=null
```

google:

```
https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=asddvdfv
https://plus.google.com/u/0/xxx
```

what is the best practice when dealing with url?

Comment: Sorry but that is for webmasters to decide. On SO you post a question for a programming question. So if you're stuck in rewrite rules then you can definitely ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod rewrite with URL is used for making smart readable URL in browser, so search engines can read them correctly. Also its meaningful URL so user can also read URL with meaning. So most of directory listing or informative pages are rewritten with mod rewrite.

When there is searching activity or too many parameters in the query string such as param1=..., param2=..., or when dynamic parameters are used in URL its not beneficial to write meaningful URL and in that case mix URL should be used

if in listing pages where you used meaningful URL (with mod rewrite) and you additionally using some dynamic parameters like paging parameters, its not necessary to rewrite them also, but you can in this situation pass those parameters as query sting like you see in second Facebook link